# Segre embedding of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1-\Delta$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to try that if $S$ is the Segre's embedding $S\Bigl(\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1-\Delta\Bigr)$ is an affine variety. Any hints?

Comment: The diagonal $\Delta \subset X=\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is a hyperplane section in the Segre embedding $C \subset \mathbb P^3$. The complement of a hyperplane in $\mathbb P^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^3$, so $X \cap \mathbb A^3$ is a quadric surface in affine space hence affine.

Comment: @TabesBridges that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal $\Delta\subset X = \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is a divisor of type $(1,1)$ hence arises as a hyperplane section in the Segre embedding $X \subset \mathbb P^3$. The complement of a hyperplane in $\mathbb P^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^3$, so $X \cap \mathbb A^3$ exhibits your complement as a quadric surface in affine space, hence it is affine.

More generally, the complement of an ample divisor on a projective variety is always affine by a similar argument.

Comment: Did you mean that a complement of an ample divisor on projective variety is affine?

Comment: @AshwathRabindranath of course, thank you.